# Проблема с запросом в базе данных mysql

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблицы "дороги" и "города" в БД. Начало и конец в таблице дороги это id городов. Не могу добавить ссылки:

дороги - **prntscr.com/aspd78** и города - **prntscr.com/aspdi3**.

 Мне нужно таблица где  столбцы: 

города.id, города.название, города.х, города.у, дороги.расстояние. 
Пример **prntscr.com/aspdsh**
Это запрос:

```
(SELECT * 
 FROM города 
 where id in (select начало 
              from дороги 
              where конец= "5")) 
 UNION 
(SELECT * 
 FROM города 
 where id in (select конец 
              from дороги 
              where начало=" 5 "))
```

Но в этой таблице нету "дороги.расстояние". Если в запросе хотя бы один из in сработает, то мне нужно взять из строки  расстояние и  добавить к  таблице.

Пробовал делать так:

```
(SELECT города.id, города.название , города.x , города.y, дороги.расстояние FROM города , дороги where города.id in (select начало from дороги where конец= "5")) 
UNION (SELECT города.id, города.название , города.x , города.y, дороги.расстояние FROM города , дороги  where города.id in (select конец from дороги where начало="5"))
```

Comment: Вам нужна что ли сумма длин дорог выходящих из данного города ? тогда никакой in не нужен, делаете join городов с дорогами по условию `начало=городId or конец=городId`, группируете по городам и берете sum(расстояние)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT города.*, дороги.расстояние FROM города
INNER JOIN дороги ON города.id = дороги.начало
WHERE дороги.конец = 5)
UNION
(SELECT города.*, дороги.расстояние FROM города
INNER JOIN дороги ON города.id = дороги.конец
WHERE дороги.начало = 5)
```

Comment: Спасибо . Работает